# Translucent window with Windows look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, transparency, look-and-feel

I'm playing with JDK7's translucent window support and find that it doesn't work well with Windows look and feel.

Here's my code:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Translucent Window");
        frame.setOpacity(0.5F);
        frame.setSize(640, 360);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code correctly displays a translucent window. However, if I set the Windows look and feel:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

an exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
```

If I disable the frame decoration with `frame.setUndecorated(true)`, it works again but that is not what I want because the title bar is missing. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial to understand how to make a `JFrame` Transparent or Translucent

http://blogofjavacrazy.blogspot.in/2007/03/transparent-window-in-java.html

I stumbled upon a neat little hack that instead of actually being transparent, it takes a screenshot and adds that little segment as the background.

**See this Link:**

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack41/index.html

Comment: Now that JDK7 delivers native support for translucent windows, why should I stick to the ugly `Robot` solution?

Comment: @ZhaoYi, i gave you a solution that i used in my project, if you think that jdk7 provides a better opportunity to get the work done, then its always better to adopt to it....

Comment: I have also used the `Robot` solution before, but it doesn't work when the content behind the "translucent" window is something animated (e.g. a gif or a movie)...

Answer (score 0):

This is really stupid.  Under Java 6 with `AWTUtilities`, this works just fine.

You'll want to read this though.

[Is The Java Tutorials Translucent Window example giving trouble to those playing with jdk7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259269/is-the-java-tutorials-translucent-window-example-giving-trouble-to-those-playing)