# Transparent JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparent, jdialog

I am working with Swing Application. I have one Frame as parent view. Inside parent **JFrame** I am using **JDialog** as child element. My JFrame background color is white. I want to create **JDialog as transparent** so when my JDailog is display inside JFrame at that time I am able to **see background of my JFrame**. I mean how can I create transparent inside JFrame.

Comment: Refer to this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631021/how-to-set-transparent-background-of-jdialog <

Thank you.

Comment: First, you can't "add" a window to a window. Second, you should start by having a look at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).  Also note, despite what the screen shots show, I've not yet been able to make this work with the native (system) look and feel without making the window undecorated, only metal seems to be able to do this